# Advanced Filter with Number as Text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with advanced filter in Excel.

I will make it simple to let you understand and reproduce the same problem.

There is a **Table T1** with data

[image: Table T1]

And a secondary **Table T2** that is a clone of T1 but empty

I will use T2 **for advance filtering** T1

[image: Table T2]

Ill do it through a macro that i created, but you can simply **click on advanced filter and select the second table after filling it up in the diagonal with the "searched value"**, i will use the SEARCH FIELD bar and a macro to this purpose and apply the filter with something like that:

```
T2.SetDiagonalValue val
T1.Range.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, T2.Range
```

Here is what happen if i write 572 in the Search Field

[image: Table T1 Search 572]

[image: Table T2 Range]

This is the intermediate step made by my macro:

[image: Adv Filter]

Result:

[image: Result]

And there is the problem:

In the **T1 table** i **have some columns** one of them have Postal Code (CAP) **with cells formatted as Text** but **written with only numbers**.

If i use Advanced Filter to search Text, it will work: example

[image: Table T1 Search Text]

[image: Table T2 Data]

But if i **try to search NUMERIC VALUE** it will work only if the searched value **match entire cell contents**, and PARTIALLY WORK (he will show only result of number in cells formatted as TEXT, **the cell with yellow background is formatted as NUMBER**) if i place a Jolly character in the search field:

Not Working:

[image: Not Working]

Not Showing yellow cell:

[image: Partially Working]

Showing all:

[image: Working]

Instead **if a Cells is Text and start with number**, he will work only if i place the **entire starting number and at least 1 char** after it:

Searching for 622SVCB, Not Working:

[image: Not Working]

Working:

[image: Working]

Each column has been set as "TEXT" except the cells with Yellow Background. Why this happen?

Comment: when you write `formally` do you mean `formally` or do you mean `formerly`? There is a difference. It would help if you could reduce your data sample to just three columns. It's a bit much to go through, and from the screen shots we can't really see what the real underlying data is. It could be numbers with formatting. It could be text. That does not come across in a screen shot.

Comment: Edited with smaller table and better explanation, with formally i mean written ONLY with number

Comment: Are you able to use AutoFilter instead?

Comment: @davesexcel yeah but i was wondering why the advance filter consider numeric string different from a normal string. If you format it as text it should consider it equal to a normal string

Comment: Yeah, I hate working with tables, I don't use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer your question:

1. even though all your table is format as text, the highlighted field in yellow is obvious still a number, as it is still aligned to the RIGHT
2. the criteria matrix is applied as a text filter (something like the screenshot 1, but NOT as screenshot 2). and a text filter will not apply to a number unless it is exact match
   [image]

[image]

To solve  your issue:

1. add a line of code to the table to force every column to text before apply the filter
2. add * to all search value so that it is read as text as well

Code

```
T2.SetDiagonalValue val & "*"

'sample code to force the column to TEXT 

Range("Table1[[#All],[TEXT WITH NUMBER]]").TextToColumns 
Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[TEXT WITH NUMBER]]"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, 
FieldInfo:=Array(0, 2)

'end of sample code

T1.Range.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, T2.Range
```

here is the result i get:

[image]

Hope that this would help

Comment: It works, thanks, but still strange that the AdvancedFilter method didn't have an overload for specify which type of "type" you are looking for...

Answer (score 3):

When approaching the Advanced Filter in Excel, try to keep a few things in mind:

- The expression for `Criteria range` should evaluate to `TRUE` or `FALSE`
- When entering a number in `Criteria range`, Excel is going to look for that *exact* number (not higher, not lower), regardless of how the number is formatted on the spreadsheet
- Excel assumes the `Criteria range` is preceded with `=` ***unless*** the filter begins with a different operator (i.e. `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `<>`)
- Regardless of how **TableT1** is formatted, Excel is going to view the `Criteria range` exactly as typed. For example, if the `Criteria range` is *all* numbers (e.g. `123`), Excel is going to look for a numerical match. If the `Criteria range` is all letters *or* a combination of letters and numbers (e.g. `abc` or `abc123`), Excel is going to compare based on text characters.

From what I can tell, your filter isn't working on partial numbers because you're essentially asking Excel to find that exact number, which doesn't exist in your "database". If you precede the criteria in **TableT2** with an operator, you should get the results you're seeking.

**Filter criteria** (`TableT2`)

[image: Filter criteria]

**Filtered results** (`TableT1`)

[image: Filtered results]

Comment: I appreciate your explanation but R3uK found also a solution to the problem!